# Restricting uib-datepicker to just one year

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, uidatepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-ui-datepicker

How do I fix the uib-datepicker to just one year. (say current year only).

I tried searching but all that I could find was to restrict calendar to year mode only. I tried setting `year:2016`  in datepicker-options but it didn't work.

Any suggestions ???

Answer (score 0):

You can to use `minDate` and `maxDate` properties in the `datepicker-options` object as described in the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker).

The following code shows a datepicker limited to the current year:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['ui.bootstrap']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
  };
  
  $scope.dateOptions = {
    minDate: moment().startOf('year').toDate(),
    maxDate: moment().endOf('year').toDate()
  };
  
  $scope.format = 'dd-MMMM-yyyy';

  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-animate.min.js "></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-touch.min.js "></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.2.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" show-button-bar="false" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I used moment [`startOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/), [`endOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) and [`toDate`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) to get the first and the last days of the current year as Date objects.

Comment: I already got this..But this is not helpful as I have to restrict date again based on my specific conditions for different rows in a table. FOr example your code enables the entire year. I want entire year should be visible but certain months in past should be non-selectable

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari sorry but you never mentionted these conditions in your original question, how can an answer satify them? The problem is that what you are asking is not what you need. I suggest to edit your question (or ask a new one) specifying the additional conditions.